# In Patchett's 'Commonwealth', how does Bert know where Fix lives?

Tags: ann-patchett, commonwealth

Ann Patchett's *Commonwealth* opens in the 1960s with Bert Cousins showing up at the christening party of Fix Keating's daughter Franny:

> Albert Cousins hadn't been invited to the party. He'd passed Dick Spencer in the hallway of the courthouse on Friday talking to a cop, some cop Cousins didn't know but who maybe looked familiar the way cops do. "See you Sunday," the cop had said, and walked away. Cousins asked Spencer, "What's Sunday?" Dick Spencer explained that Fix Keating had a new kid, and that there was going to be a christening party.
>
> <sub>Patchett, Ann. *Commonwealth*. New York: Harper, 2016. pp. 14–15.</sub>

Well after the party is underway, Cousins decides on the spur of the moment to attend it, as an escape from his work and family life:

> But by Sunday he couldn't do it again, not the children or the wife or the job, and so he pulled up the memory of a christening party he hadn't been invited to. Teresa looked at him, her face bright for a minute. Thirty-one years old and she still had freckles over the bridge of her nose and spreading over her cheeks. She often said that she wished they took their kids to church, even if he didn't believe in church or God or any of it. She thought it would be a good thing for them to do as a family, and this party might be the place to start. They could all go together.
>
> "No," he said. "It's a work thing."
>
> She blinked. "A christening party?"
>
> "The guy's a cop." He hoped she wouldn't ask the cop's name because at that particular moment he couldn't remember it.
>
> <sub>p. 17</sub>

It is plausible how Cousins learns about the party and why he decides to attend. But how does he know the Keatings' address? He can't even remember Fix Keating's name, so he can't look it up in the phone book. He can't call Spencer to ask for it, because Spencer would already be at the party by then. So how does he know where to go?

I also have a [follow-up question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/25928/289) about Spencer's inexplicable silence regarding Cousins.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Disclaimer: I haven't read this book. I'll happily delete my answer if it doesn't make sense within the context of the story. (My first answer was going to be that, judging only from the quotes you've provided, it's not clear that the semi-recognised cop is the same person as Fix Keating, rather than just another person attending the same christening. I realise, however, that other context makes this clear.)</sup>

> He hoped she wouldn't ask the cop's name because **at that particular moment** he couldn't remember it.

(Emphasis added.) Presumably he remembered it later, or he could have called someone else from the DA office, not Spencer but someone who knew Spencer well enough to be aware of his former partner's name or even address. It's mentioned that nobody else from the DA office was invited except Spencer.

Notice that, when Fix Keating opens his front door to see Albert Cousins, the latter immediately holds out a hand and addresses him as "Fix". He must have remembered, or been informed of, the guy's name before getting there, at least. Not just from the phone book, either, as that would presumably list his full name of Francis Xavier rather than the nickname Fix.

Comment: You're right that the cop Cousins overhears talking to Spencer might not be Fix himself. I assumed it was, but the text doesn't specify either way. I guess I find it hard to believe that Cousins could call someone to find Fix's name and address. It's a Sunday, he'd have to call someone's home. And from some place other than his own home, because he can't risk Teresa's overhearing him asking someone for Spencer's ex-partner's name and address; the game would be up.