# In Patchett's 'Commonwealth', why doesn't Spencer tell Fix about Beverly's affair?

Tags: character-analysis, commonwealth, ann-patchett

Here is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/25927/289) about Ann Patchett's *Commonwealth*. I'm unclear about Dick Spencer's role in concealing the affair that Bert Cousins is having with Beverly Keating.

Spencer is a former cop turned lawyer who is a colleague of Cousins' in the district attorney's office. As a cop, he had been Fix Keating's partner, and they remain close. Cousins overhears Fix inviting Spencer to his daughter's christening and crashes the party. There, Cousins and Fix's wife Beverly are attracted to each other and share a clandestine kiss. Later, they begin an affair that lasts a couple of years before they leave their respective spouses to get married.

In the first place, Spencer must have been surprised at Cousins' showing up. He knows that Cousins has not been invited. But the novel gives no indication that he asks Cousins or Keating about this. Secondly, the affair Beverly and Bert commence soon becomes common knowledge at the DA's office. When Cousins leaves his wife Teresa for Beverly, he also quits his job and moves to Virginia. Teresa thereupon becomes a stenographer at the same DA's office:

> The lawyers in the DA's office had a small, collective sense of guilt about having covered for Bert during his long affair. They thought they owed Teresa a break now that he was gone and so they offered her the job.
>
> <sub>Patchett, Ann. *Commonwealth*. New York: Harper, 2016. p. 63.</sub>

So Spencer must have known about the affair. But he does not tell Fix about it, even though they remain friends. Fix consistently speaks warmly and thinks highly of Spencer, even following in his footsteps to go to law school. By contrast, there is no indication that Spencer and Cousins are friends. Yet Spencer keeps silent about the adulterous relationship.

Why does Spencer keep silent, first, when Cousins shows up uninvited to the christening, and second, when he commences an affair with Beverly?